# how to implement a pause screen in unity5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a pause screen in Unity5. Currently I use an additive loadscenemode to achieve this but every time I resume game I have to reload the scene again. I wonder Is there a way to just add the pause screen scene and unload it without affecting the currently rendering scene(so that I dont have to reload it every time I pause)? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy! You have to set the `Time.timeScale` to `0` and back to `1` again when un-pause.
For a pause menu I'd recommend showing/hiding a semi-transparent canvas.
For further read, see [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) and [Canvas](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) in docs.
**EDIT:**
So basically, remove your pause scene (even though you could load it in [Additive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html) mode I wouldn't recommend that for a pause menu) and replace it with a canvas having a menu on it (which you probably already coded but in the main menu -or similar- scene).
I'd stick with this method as the pause menu is probably different than the "full" menu you offer before the game is started (and also can be affected by events / game phases / etc)

Comment: @sunsflower Cheers. If you like the solution it would be nice if you could accept, maybe even upvote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry that I dont have enough reputation to vote or accept....It says I must have at least 15 reputation points..

Comment: @sunsflower haha, I didn't know that, it's strange! Another time then! ;) Cheers!

Comment: by the way, how to make the camera persist when loading a new scene? I've tried to use DontDestroyOnLoad but when I need to switch back to the scene where camera is added another camera is created....